# Start Celery worker on production. Using Django/Python on Azure/linux app service

Tags: django, azure, asynchronous, celery, message-queue

I have a website with an API that customers can send their API-post-calls. These API's have attachments in form of a PDFs or similar that gets stored in a folder /MEDIA/Storage/. The app is written in Django.

The API-call gets stored in a model through DRF and serializers. After the data is stored some logic is done, emails os sent, lookups and storing in data-tables etc. Since this takes so much time. I implemented Celery (Azure Cache for Redis as Broker) in my app, so that only the first storage in model is done as usual. The rest us queued up through Celery.

This works well on my local machine (mac os). But not on production (Azure/Linux).

I have tried git hooks, but i cannot get it working.
I have tried some terminal through ssh on the azure VM, but no luck...
I have looked into Daemonization but it was complicated.

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'redis://:<password>=@<appname>.redis.cache.windows.net:6379/0'
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = 'django-db'
CELERY_CACHE_BACKEND = 'django-cache'
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import, unicode_literals
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'hapionline.settings')

app = Celery('hapionline')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace="CELERY")
app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**views.py**

```
class ProcSimpleList(generics.CreateAPIView): # Endast Create för att skapa en proc
    serializer_class = ProcSimpleSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAdminOrReadOnly,)
    lookup_url_kwarg = 'proc_id'

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        q = serializer.save()
        # Queue from starting worker. Queue created when starting cereal.
        transaction.apply_async(queue='high_priority', args=(q.proc_id, self.request.user.pk))
```

Local machine: All works well with the command: celery -A hapionline worker -l info -Q high_priority

Production: I do not know where to run the command on the production server? 
If the worker is started on the local machine, it starts the Azure Cache, and calling the production environment API works. But since the worker is started locally the Paths too attached files in the API are incorrect and local, not production-like. /User/../Media/.. instead of /wwwroot/../media/..

Any ideas? How do I start a worker on the production VM? Is there a way to run a the start worker "script" after the git push azure master?

Answer (score 2):

I skipped Azure and moved the app to Heroku. This worked as a charm.